# Migrating from Time Machine without Migration Assistant

Tags: macos, migration, bug

I want to change my mid-2010 iMac with the latest iMac of my parents. Because we both use Time Machine, well, the easiest way *would* be to restore both of them from the backups.
However, there is a bug in Lion that causes my mac to hang just before completing the file transfer. Is it possible to just drag all contents of the backup to Macintosh HD without problems or are there any workarounds?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drag documents, but you have to reinstall your applications, setting up again mail accounts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using OSX 10.9.2, Migration assistant kept crashing when trying to transfer from my old Mac. The Apple Tech Support dude said to just do a Time Machine backup of the old computer, then use Migration assistant to transfer from that TM backup to the new computer.